# using .htaccess with paths in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm working on a script and I want to make the links such as:

```
www.mysite.com/sites/info/siteid 
www.mysite.com/sites/edit/siteid
www.mysite.com/sites/delete/siteid
```

I know that I should use RewriteRule. here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^sites/(.*)$ sites.php?info=$1 [L]
```

So, in php, I want to get /info or /edit or /delete like `$_GET['info'];` and so on.
also, I want to get `siteid` in same way

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the arguments at `/` should work

```
RewriteRule ^/sites/(.*)/(.*)$ sites.php?info=$1&siteid=$2 [L]
```